# Is it possible to Convert ArrayList < SelectItem> to ArrayList<Long> in java

Tags: java, long-integer

I have a list like following:

```
List<SelectItem> measurementList;
```

I want to assign `measurementList.get(i)` into a `Long` variable.

For example I want to assign it in the following way:

```
Long sd = measurementList.get(0);
```

But, it is showing type mismatch. That is really obvious. How can I assign the value from `measurementList.get(0)` to a `Long` variable.

Thanks

Code are given below:

```
public List<SelectItem> measurementList(Long coModAssetId)
{
//  log.info("Start");
//  log.debug("finding MeasurementSeneorTypeList instance by example using dbMeasurementSeneorTypeList");

    List<SelectItem> results;

    try {
        // Add SELECT with a nested select to get the 1st row
        String queryString = "SELECT M.Measurement_Id, M.NAME" +
                "                      FROM ems.COMPANY_MODULE_ASSET CMA, " +
                "                           ems.Asset_Measurement Am," +
                "                           ems.MEASUREMENT M" + 
                "                     WHERE CMA.Co_Mod_Asset_Id = ?" +
                "                       And Cma.Asset_Id = Am.Asset_Id  " +
                "                       AND AM.MEASUREMENT_ID = M.MEASUREMENT_ID" +     
                "                     GROUP BY M.measurement_id, M.NAME" +
                "                     ORDER BY M.name";

        MeasurementSeneorTypeListWork work = new MeasurementSeneorTypeListWork();
        work.coModAssetId = coModAssetId;
        work.queryString = queryString;

        getSession().doWork(work);

        results = work.results;

    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
    //  log.error("getMostRecentObservationId() failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
    //log.info("End");
    return results;

}
```

Class definition

```
public class MeasurementSeneorTypeListWork implements Work {
    List<SelectItem> results = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    private String queryString;
    private Long  coModAssetId;

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);

        int index = 1;
        ps.setLong(index++, coModAssetId);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {   
            //String userName = PropertyReader.getLabel(rs.getString(2));   
            Long id = rs.getLong(1);
            SelectItem item = new SelectItem(id, null);
            results.add(item);
        }       


        rs.close();
        ps.close();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have your `SelectItem` implement a method which returns a `long`?

Comment: Does `SelectItem` have a `toLong()` method?

Comment: What is `SelectItem`?

Comment: Are you referring to `javax.faces.model.SelectItem`? We have no chance of helping you if we don't know what you're talking about :/

Comment: Edited my post. You can have a idea by seeing the Code. Thanks

Comment: Yes, kind of, but with the imports it would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `SelectItem` type is `javax.faces.model.SelectItem`, then you have a `getValue()` method that you can use.

```
Long sd = (Long) measurementList.get(i).getValue();
```

Note: you're using the 2-argument constructor `SelectItem(Object value, String label)` to create your items for the list, but since the second parameter is always `null`, you could use `SelectItem(Object value)` instead.

Comment: No problem, you can still tick the answer for later readers ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.longValue()` method:

```
(measurementList.get(i)).longValue()
```

This returns the numeric value represented by this object after conversion to type long.